# Checking characters in a string

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I want to wrote a program which checks every character in a string. If the two characters are same in a row I want to increase count by 1. The program should scan all the characters and give us a value. T is for deciding how many String's we will enter.

For example: (input)
5
AAAA
BBBBB
ABABABAB
BABABA
AAABBB

Ouput
3
4
0
0
4

But I get 0
3
4
0
0

Could you help? What I have done wrong?

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.math.*;
 import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int i,T,j,count;
       String S;
       char K;
       count = 0;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       T = scan.nextInt(); 
       for (i = 0; i <= T - 1; i++)
       {
           count = 0;
           S = scan.nextLine();
           char[] list = new char[S.length()];
           for(j = 0; j <= S.length() - 1; j++)
           {
               list[j] = S.charAt(j);    
           }
           for(j = 1; j <= S.length() - 1; j++)
           {
              if(list[j - 1] == list[j])
              {
                  count++;
              }     
           }
          System.out.println(count);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually what u want?? please explain..

Comment: I want it to check every character and compare with the following one. For instance if list[i - 1] == list[i] count should increase by one. I want the program to check it for every character in the string.

Comment: Scan internally again.. it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like the below should help you out, It first requires a number of strings that will be entered and then in the entered string will count the number of times a character is the same as the previous character. It wont take a series of strings though, it will do them one by one, see the example output below:

```
   public static void main(String[] args){  
       int numInput;
       String inputString;
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       numInput = scanner.nextInt();

       for(int y = 0; y < numInput;y++){           
           inputString = scanner.next();
           char[] chars = inputString.toCharArray();
           int counter = 0;

           char curr;
           for(int x = 0; x < chars.length;x++){
               curr = chars[x];
             if(x>0){
                if(chars[x-1] == curr){
                    counter++;
                }
             }
           }
           System.out.println("Count for string " + inputString + " was " + counter);
       }
       scanner.close();
   }
```

Testing:

```
5
AASAAB
Count for string AASAAB was 2
AAAAAA
Count for string AAAAAA was 5
AAVAAD
Count for string AAVAAD was 2
MOOMOO
Count for string MOOMOO was 2
MAAAAAA
Count for string MAAAAAA was 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, T, j, count;
    String S;
    char K;
    count = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    T = scan.nextInt();
    for (i = 0; i <= T - 1; i++) {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        count = 0;
        S = scan.nextLine();
        char[] list = new char[S.length()];
        for (j = 0; j <= S.length() - 1; j++) {
            list[j] = S.charAt(j);
        }
        for (j = 1; j <= S.length() - 1; j++) {
            if (list[j - 1] == list[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
 at Solution.main(Solution.java:21)